# Check if table cell has a german number?

Tags: jquery, regex

i like to check if the table cell has a german number e.g.:

```
<table id="mytab"><tr>
<td>0,02</td>
<td>100,23454544</td>
<td>1000,23</td>
<td>1.000,23</td>
<td>String no number</td></tr>
</table>
```

i try it like this:

```
const euAmountFormat = /^\d{1,3}(\.\d{3})*(,\d{2})$/

var cln = $('#mytab').clone();
cln.find('td').each(function() {
   let text = $(this).text().trim();
   if (euAmountFormat.test(text)) {
       ...
   }
});
```

All of the above td's are numbers except the last one. But my regex did not detect them correctly. What i need to change?

Can somebody help?

Thanks

Comment: `(,\d{2})` is required, did you mean to make it optional? `(,\d{2})?`

Comment: it could be 1 or more numbers after the ,

Comment: Trying your code, `0,02` and `1.000,23` are the only ones matched; it definitely does not "detect all of them correctly".

Comment: Yes i tried an some of them where not detected but why? I am not firm with regex at this time so i dont now whats wrong with my regex.

Comment: Well for example, `(,\d{2})$` matches two numbers after a comma. `100,23454544` has 8 numbers after the comma so why would you expect that to match? Or `1000,23` which has 4 numbers before the comma and the regex matches sets of 3 numbers before the comma.

Comment: Try `^(?:0|[1-9]\d+|[1-9]\d{0,2}(?:\.\d{3})*)(?:,\d+)?$` to match all of your examples except the last ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/95DGRF/1))

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/dclaCc/1

Comment: `/^\d{1,}(\.\d{3})*(,\d{2})$/` will catch the 1000,23